# Passing properties vs local variables as method parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c

e.g. a `Person` class has a property `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;` and two methods: an initialisation method `- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name;` and another method `- (void)doSomethingWithName:(NSString *)name;` as follows:

```
- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name = name;
        [self doSomethingWithName:name];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)doSomethingWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    NSLog(@"My name is: %@", name)
}
```

While in this case we're passing the local variable `name` from `- initWithName:` to `- doSomethingWithName:`, we could achieve the same result by passing `self.name` to `- doSomethingWithName:`. In fact, we could even rewrite the `- doSomethingWithName:` method as such:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithName
{
    NSLog(@"My name is: %@", self.name)
}
```

Which of these approaches is considered best practice and why?

Comment: (personal opinion): I would generally recommend taking it as a parameter. This allows you greater future flexibility in any changes you make both within and outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

The two approaches do different things.

The form

```
- (void)doSomethingWithName:(NSString *)name
```

Is more like a global function. It takes a parameter and does something with it.

The form that doesn't take a parameter is an instance method. You ask an object to do something with *its* name.

Neither is better than the other. It's a question of need/intent.

It's like asking a chef "What's better, a whisk or a spatula?" Neither is better than the other. They are different tools suited to different tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches could be problematic: you should not use accessors or message self in your init method.

Think about what can happen if some subclass overrides *name* accessor or *doSomethingWithName*. A subclass would expect a fully initialised object, while the reality is that its *init* method is yet to be executed...